# How to enable HTTPS monitoring in FiddlerCore WITHOUT decrypting SSL

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, fiddler

I need to be able to monitor all requests (HTTP & HTTPS) going out of IE. I am only interested in the headers and the cookies, so that I don't need to decrypt the SSL encrypted body. But I don't see a way of setting FiddlerCore as a proxy for HTTPS without enabling decryptSSL.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: In response to your title-question: 
If you don't want FiddlerCore to decrypt SSL, then pass 
(FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default & 
~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL) as the parameter when 
calling .Startup()

Answer (score 6):

In HTTPS *everything* is encrypted: query string, headers, cookies, body and everything. So you cannot view the headers and cookies without decrypting everything anyway.

Comment: Correct. FiddlerCore can be used to proxy SSL traffic without decrypting it (that's the default config, IIRC), but that won't provide you with access to the encrypted HTTPS headers.

Comment: If that's true how does HTTPAnalyzer displays the headers and cookies of an HTTPS exchange (it also reports the requests&responses though encrypted)

Comment: I don't know, but I assume it works the same way: by decrypting the entire request/response.

Comment: HTTPAnalyzer thunks the network stack after decryption, and simply examines the network traffic in your computer's memory.